# (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Point'

Tags: psycopg2

I'm trying to add data to postgresql data base in flask framework using flask sqlalchemy, geoalchemy2, but when trying to add point data I'm getting this error,

```
(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'Point'
```

Anyone with way through it or resource that can help me get the solution for this

Comment: You can refer this link [enter link description here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239198/adding-geopandas-dataframe-to-postgis-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue but with with the multipolygon type.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.programmingerror: (psycopg2.programmingerror) can't adapt type 'multipolygon'
```

The issue was that the Shapely object needed to be converted to a WKBElement before being added to the model field.

The solution was to convert the Shapely object using the `from_shape` function (see: https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.6/shape.html)

Here's an example assuming you've already defined your orm models:

```py
from geoalchemy2.shape import from_shape
from shapely.geometry import Point

# import local orm model that has a geoalchemy2 Geometry column
from orm import PointOfInterest

# convert point using from_shape
my_point = from_shape(Point(16.62, 24.68), srid=4326)

with Session() as session:
    session.add(
        PointOfInterest(
            name='example',
            geometry=my_point,
        )
    )
    session.commit()
```